# Autodesk forge Markup extension markers position not matching x y z values

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the markup extension that can be found at https://github.com/wallabyway/markupExt and have not changed the code within the extension except setting this.size to a bigger value to make the marker easier to find

the actual rendering of the points works fine I just can't seem to place them in a specific position on the model, they just appear floating off in the middle of empty space.

Code to generate the point

```
var dummyData = [];

    dummyData.push({
        icon: Math.round(Math.random() * 3),
        x: 129597.054373,
        y: -27184.841094,
        z: 44514.362733
    });

    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('newData', { 'detail': dummyData }));
```

I have tried feeding it values taken straight from a selected items properties and have also tried feeding it values taken from the following code (I have tried with and without the nominalise step)

```
function onMouseClick(event) {
var screenPoint = {
    x: event.clientX,
    y: event.clientY
};

var n = normalizeCoords(screenPoint)


var hitTest = viewer.impl.hitTest(n.x, n.y, true);

if (hitTest) {

    alert(hitTest.intersectPoint.x + ' ' + ' ' + hitTest.intersectPoint.y + ' ' + hitTest.intersectPoint.z)

    }
}


function normalizeCoords(screenPoint) {

var viewport = viewer.navigation.getScreenViewport();

var n = {
    x: (screenPoint.x - viewport.left) / viewport.width,
    y: (screenPoint.y - viewport.top) / viewport.height
};

return n;
}
```

The point moves when i change the x y z values but never to where I want them and am not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: The markup positions should be in the world coordinate system. Try getting the bounding box of your entire model (using `viewer.model.getBoundingBox()`) and use certain positions from within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than the code found in the other extensions that uses the viewport to offset the point I seem to have fixed it by adding `viewer.model.getData().globalOffset` to the hit test intersection values